# General strategy to decode type mismatch keys in JSON into nil when optional in Swift

Tags: json, swift, type-mismatch, jsondecoder

Here is my problem, when I receive some JSON, it happens that some values do not match the required type. I don't really mind, I'm only interested by the value when its type is correct.

For instance, the following structure:

```
struct Foo : Decodable {
    var bar : Int?
}
```

I'd like it to match these JSON:

```
{ "bar" : 42 }    => foo.bar == 42
{ "bar" : null }  => foo.bar == nil
{ "bar" : "baz" } => foo.bar == nil
```

Indeed I'm looking for an optional `Int`, so whenever it's an integer I want it, but when it's `null` or something else I want `nil`.

Unfortunately, our good old `JSONDecoder` raises a type mismatch error on the last case.

I know a manual way to do it:

```
struct Foo : Decodable {
    var bar : Int?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        self.bar = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .bar)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case bar
    }
}
```

But I have many structures, and many fields to check.

So I'd like to know if there is a general way to do it something like:

```
decoder.typeMismatchStrategy = .nilInsteadOfError // <= Don't try it at home, I know it does not exist...
```

Or maybe override `JSONDecoder`, anyway something to write once and not on every struct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to declare `var bar : Any?` Because it can be any, as you describe it.

Comment: That's not what I want, unfortunately. I only want the field to be filled when it's an `Int`. Moreover, I really do not want to leave strong type by setting `Any` everywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One approach would be to create a property wrapper that's `Decodable`  to use for these these kind of properties:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct NilOnTypeMismatch<Value> {
    var wrappedValue: Value?
}

extension NilOnTypeMismatch: Decodable where Value: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        self.wrappedValue = try? container.decode(Value.self)
    }
}
```

Then you could selectively wrap the properties that you want to special-handle:

```
struct Foo : Decodable {
    @NilOnTypeMismatch
    var bar : Int?
}
```

---

A more holistic approach would be to extend `KeyedDecodingContainer` for `Int`s, but that would apply app-wide:

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decodeIfPresent(_ type: Int.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> Int? {
        try? decode(Int.self, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible (or don't know how) to make it generic, since my guess is that this function overload is at a lower priority than a default implementation when using generics.

Comment: That's a clever idea indeed. But I was lookin for something more general on the decoding side, without having to touch the model structures. But I like it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your time... The second one also clever even if you have to write it for every type, and as you say is app-wide.